# How to pass value from table to bootstrap modal to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've fetched rows from MySQL and looped it with Bootstrap modal and I've made a form in modal from which the data is being sent to PHP script (update.php) with the help of ajax. But in return I am getting the output of last row only.
I need to get the record of specific student with its unique ID.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table class="table table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>NAME</th>
                            <th>ROLL NUMBER</th>
                            <th>CONTACT NO</th>
                            <th>ADDRESS</th>
                            <th>EDIT</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                               <?php


            $query = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY id DESC";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            if($query_run){

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $rollno = $row['rollno'];
                    $contact = $row['contact'];
                    $address = $row['address'];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $rollno . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $contact . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $address . '</td>';
                    echo "<td><button class='btn btn-link btn-custom dis' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal$id'>
  EDIT</button> </td>";
                    echo '</tr>';
                    ?>

                                                   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $id; ?>"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                       <div class="modal-content">
                                           <div class="modal-header">
                                               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                               <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">EDIT RECORD</h4>
                                           </div>
                                           <div class="modal-body">

                                               <form id="updateValues" action="update.php" method="POST" class="form">
                                                   <div class="form-group">
                                                       <label for="name">NAME</label>
                                                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="form-group">
                                                       <label for="rollno">ROLL NO</label>
                                                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rollno" id="rollno" value="<?php echo $rollno; ?>">
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="form-group">
                                                       <label for="contact">CONTACT</label>
                                                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="contact" value="<?php echo $contact; ?>">
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="form-group">
                                                       <label for="address">ADDRESS</label>
                                                       <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="address" id="address"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom" value="Save changes">
                                               </form>

                                           </div>
                                           <div class="modal-footer">
                                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                               <div id="results"></div>
                                           </div>

                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                     <?php  }
            }?>
                         </tbody>
                    </table>
</body>
</html>




JS:



                $(document).ready(function(){

                    var values, url;


                      $('#updateValues').submit(function(e){

                          e.preventDefault();
                           values = $(this).serialize();
                          url = $(this).attr('action');


                          $.post(url, values, function(data){
                             $('#results').html(data);
                          });
                      });
                });

Update.php:

<?php


 if(isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['rollno'])&&isset($_POST['contact'])&&isset($_POST['address'])){
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $rollno = $_POST['rollno'];
     $contact = $_POST['contact'];
     $address = $_POST['address'];

     echo "$id $name $rollno $contact $address";
 }else{
     echo 'ERROR!';
 }

?>
```

Comment: ids need to be unique, `updateValues` is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not tested/debugged but refactor your code similar to this:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY id DESC";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($query_run){

    $out = '
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>ROLL NUMBER</th>
                <th>CONTACT NO</th>
                <th>ADDRESS</th>
                <th>EDIT</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    ';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
            $out .= '<tr class="trID_' .$row['id']. '">';
            $out .= '<td class="td_name">' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
            $out .= '<td class="td_rollno">' . $row['rollno'] . '</td>';
            $out .= '<td class="td_contact">' . $row['contact'] . '</td>';
            $out .= '<td class="td_address">' . $row['address'] . '</td>';
            $out .= "<td><button class='td_btn btn btn-link btn-custom dis'>EDIT</button> </td>";
            $out .= '</tr>';
        }
        $out .= '</tbody></table>
        echo $out;
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(){
        $('.td_btn').click(function(){
            var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var rowID = $row.attr('class').split('_')[1];
            var name =  $row.find('.td_name').val();
            var rollno =  $row.find('.td_rollno').val();
            var contact =  $row.find('.td_contact').val();
            var address =  $row.find('.td_address').val();
            $('#frm_id').val(rowID);
            $('#frm_name').text(name);
            $('#frm_rollno').text(rollno);
            $('#frm_contact').text(contact);
            $('#frm_address').text(address);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    });//END document.ready
</script>

       <div class="modal fade" id="myModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
           <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
               <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                       <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">EDIT RECORD</h4>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">

                       <form id="updateValues" action="update.php" method="POST" class="form">
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="name">NAME</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="frm_name">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="rollno">ROLL NO</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rollno" id="frm_rollno">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="contact">CONTACT</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="frm_contact">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="address">ADDRESS</label>
                               <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="address" id="frm_address"></textarea>
                           </div>
                           <input type="hidden" name="frm_id">
                           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom" value="Save changes">
                       </form>

                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                       <div id="results"></div>
                   </div>

               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

---

Notes:

(1) Create the entire table in a variable, then output the variable all at once.

(2) You only need one modal, not one modal for each table row. Therefore, remove modal creation from inside while loop.

(3) Use jQuery to:
   (a) detect button click in row
   (b) get table data for that row
   (c) populate fields in modal
   (d) display modal
You are using Bootstrap, which uses jQuery, so it makes sense to use jQuery to do this.

(4) Using jQuery to get values from table cells vs. input fields:
   (a) `.text()` - from table cells
   (b) `.val()` - from `<input>` or `<textarea>`

---

[Here is a jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1s9u629w/1/) you can play with that demonstrates how you can use jQuery to populate the modal depending on the row that was clicked.

Comment: @UmairKhan Fixed. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Thank you sir @gibberish. Your explanation helped me alot in solving my problem.